# How to drop a table based on IF condition in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to drop a table on startup based on a condition:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from pg_class where relname = 'mytable' and relpersistence = 'u') 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable
```

Result: `Syntaxerror at 'IF', SQL state: 42601`. Why? How can I drop a table based on a condition, if I'm not allowed to use `IF`?

Comment: `drop table if exists` drops the table only if it exists so you can drop the `if not exists ... `

Comment: I only want to drop the table if it is in state `UNLOGGED`, thus I indeed need the prior select...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IF` can't be used in SQL, this is only valid for PL/pgSQL.

You need to do this with dynamic SQL inside an anonymous PL/pgSQL block. Something like:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  select count(*)
     into l_count
  from pg_class c
    join pg_namespace nsp on c.relnamespace = nsp.oid
  where c.relname = 'mytable' 
    and c.relpersistence = 'u'
    and nsp.nspname = 'public';

  if l_count = 1 then 
    execute 'drop table mytable';
  end if;

end;
$$
```

You probably should extend the `select` statement to join against `pg_namespace` and include the schema name in your where condition to make sure you are not accidently dropping a table from the wrong schema.

Comment: OK I see, thanks a lot. How would I create the join? `select * from pg_namespace` would give me the following: `nspname nspowner nspacl` `public  10       "{postgres=UC/postgres,=UC/postgres}"`, I of course only want to perform the drop on the "public" schema.

Comment: Can't this be made shorter, IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class....) THEN EXECUTE......?

Answer (score 2):

Already accepted answer by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914211/3682599) will works though  You can create a Custom Function if you want to use the same task for other tables in future, so you should create a function like below:

```
create or replace function drop_table (_tbl varchar) returns void as
$$
begin
if exists(select 1
          from pg_class c
          join pg_namespace nsp on c.relnamespace = nsp.oid
          where c.relname = ''||_tbl||'' 
            and c.relpersistence = 'u'
            and nsp.nspname = 'public') then
  execute format('DROP TABLE %s',_tbl);
  raise notice 'Table %s Deleted',_tbl;
else
  raise notice 'Table %s Not Deleted',_tbl;
end if;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

and simply call this function whenever you want

```
select drop_table('mytable');
```

or

`select drop_table('mytable_1')`