# Drop table if it has less than n records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, drop-table

I am experimenting with `postgres` and can't get this simple query to work:

```
drop table mytable if (select count(*) from mytable)<50 ;
```

This gives error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"
LINE 1: drop table tablename if (select count(*) from mytable)<50 ;
```

How do you alter/drop tables in postgres for a given condition?

Comment: Postgres doesn't support a `WHERE` or `IF` clause on `DROP TABLE`:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html.

Comment: Why do you want to?  But to answer your question put the `drop` AFTER the `if`.  And start reading the documentation before asking strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dynamic SQL works for this (See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914211/3285138)) -

```
do
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  select count(*)
     into l_count
  from pg_class c
    join pg_namespace nsp on c.relnamespace = nsp.oid
  where c.relname = 'mytable' 
    and nsp.nspname = 'public';
  if l_count < 50 then 
    execute 'drop table mytable';
  end if;
end;
$$
```