# How to conditionally drop a database in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Whereas [How to drop a table based on IF condition in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913856/how-to-drop-a-table-based-on-if-condition-in-postgres) solves the problem of conditionally dropping a table, it doesn't work for dropping a database because:

```
ERROR:  DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function
```

I want to drop a database but only if it is has no user tables.
How can I execute any kind of `IF` if I can't do it from function?

Comment: The function issue is a subset of `DROP DATABASE` not being allowed in a transaction. Functions run in a transaction, hence the error. This is going to be something you need  to do from outside Postgres using a script.

Comment: Ah. So the best I can do is to move the `IF` control out of the postgres script into the hosting shell script; and then I can ask psql to drop database unconditionally

Answer (score 0):

You'll first have to connect to the database, count the tables, connect to a different database (for example `postgres`), revoke connections to the database from everybody, kill all database sessions and run `DROP TABLE`.